# Integrate vertex with existing spring web application

Tags: spring-mvc, integration, vert.x

I have an existing Spring based web application. I want to integrate vertx within the application.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have a look at the [Vert.x with Spring](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples) section in the examples repository on GitHub.

Comment: i was looking more like integrating vert.x without actually having to create another class. But your solution works as well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot it is fairly simple

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mypackage", "com.myotherpackage" })
public class MyApplication {

    @Autowired
    private MainVerticle mainVertical;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void deployServerVerticle() {
        Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(mainVertical);
    }

}
```

The `@PostConstuct` allows you to deploy all the verticals you want (all the properties are set at this point).

And it goes without saying that the MainVerticle should be marked with the `@Component` annotation.